# SQLAlchemy raises NoForeignKeyError with Many to One relations

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, orm

I have three different classes I want to integrate with my database using `SQLAlchemy`. The relation I have is like `Class2` object are main classes, each `Class2` can have multiple `Class1` objects which `Class1` should have one to one relation with `Class2`. Each `Class3` has two one to one relations with two different classes of type `Class1`.

```py
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


class Class1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Class1s'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    owner = relationship("Class2", back_populates="Class1s")

    crypto_type = Column(String)
    balance = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, default=0)



class Class2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Class2s'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)



class Class3(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Class3'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    amount = Column(Integer)

    source = relationship("Class1")
    destination = relationship("Class1")


class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = db.create_engine("sqlite:///database.db", echo=True)

        session = sessionmaker()
        session.configure(bind=self.engine)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = Database()
    print('Database Initialized Successfully!')

    user = Class2()
```

This raises the following error:

```sh
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Class1.owner - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Please read [Basic Relationship Patters](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html)*

You indeed need to define how the tables underlying your classes are linked, which is done using the [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html?highlight=foreignkey#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey)

```
class Class1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Class1s'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    owner = relationship("Class2", back_populates="Class1s")

    crypto_type = Column(String)
    balance = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, default=0)



class Class2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Class2s'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    class1_id = Column(ForeignKey('Class1s.id'))  # <!-- NEW **
    # Class1s = relationship("Class2", back_populates="owner")
```

In your case you will also need to be explicit when defining the relationship between the Class3 and Class1 (I guess, Transaction and TransactionLeg).
*See [Handling Multiple Join Paths](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths)* for more information.

```
class Class3(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Class3'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    amount = Column(Integer)

    source_id = Column(ForeignKey('Class2s.id'))  # <!-- NEW **
    destination_id = Column(ForeignKey('Class2s.id'))  # <!-- NEW **

    source = relationship("Class1", foreign_keys=[source_id])  # <!-- MODIFIED **
    destination = relationship("Class1",  foreign_keys=[destination_id])  # <!-- MODIFIED **
```

---

*Please note that nothing above is tested and might contain typos.*